# Location Manager smallest displacement with high accuracy android

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager, android-location

i am trying to implement an application that uses users current location. Due to the fact that i need the PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY i would like to stop these gps updates when the users doesn't move. Currently my code looks like this.

```
mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
mLocationClient.connect();
```

and in on connected o do the following stuff.

```
Location location = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
locationrequest = LocationRequest.create(); 
locationrequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10f);
locationrequest.setInterval(10*1000);
locationrequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationrequest, this);
```

The problem is that the smallestDisplacement doesn't work at all. I've tried to remove the :

```
locationrequest.setInterval(10*1000);
```

but after i remove it i don't receive any other location updates. Could somebody tell me what am i doing wrong?